# If we can use 'new' operator for all the things that 'clone' is use do, So why there is a particular method as 'clone' in java?

Tags: java, clone, new-operator

I asked this question from my faculty she replied new operator takes more processing time then clone, Is it correct? And Clone vs copy constructor is not my question !.If it would be 'CLONE VS NEW OPERATOR', then it may be correct.

Comment: `clone()` is slower than `new`, because it does more work for you.

Comment: GOT MY ANSWER "new" creates an empty object. "Clone" creates an object and populates it with the data from the original object.              @Oliver Charlesworth if you dont know the answer, so kind please let others try it.